# Getting the breakdown of where my user sources are

Tags: bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-analytics

I've got a Facebook Messenger Bot and I'm using Facebook Analytics to get insights about user behaviour. Is there a way of getting the breakdown of where my user sources are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean exactly by "user sources".
But for Messenger Bot App you can easily create a new Breakdown, by picking as event name "New Messenger Bot Users" and breakdown by Region.

See image below as an example:
[New Messenger Bot Users by Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGMrb.png)

Comment: I am referring to where they came from. E.g: Referral, Facebook, Direct Link, etc.
FB staff told me it's impossible for the moment! Thanks anyway!